# Ranking based on significant difference in list of lists

Tags: r, list, sorting, ranking

I have a list of lists, where each list is sorted. What I want to look into is how many times a certain element has appeared in a specific position and take into account if the value is significantly different from the previous element. (For example in the first list gs, ms, bofa and citi have the same value but they are ranked differently). I realize that the length of the rankings would not be the same because each list's elements are different. How can I do this in a manner where it is correct and also shows the result in a decent way?

What I have so far with ranking solidly based on the sort function output:

```
dput(degree.l)
list(c(schwab = 0, pnc = 0.0344827586206897, jpm = 0.0862068965517241, 
amex = 0.0862068965517241, gs = 0.103448275862069, ms = 0.103448275862069, 
bofa = 0.103448275862069, citi = 0.103448275862069, wf = 0.120689655172414, 
spgl = 0.120689655172414, brk = 0.137931034482759), c(schwab = 0.0166666666666667, 
pnc = 0.05, ms = 0.0666666666666667, spgl = 0.0833333333333333, 
jpm = 0.1, bofa = 0.1, wf = 0.1, amex = 0.1, gs = 0.116666666666667, 
brk = 0.116666666666667, citi = 0.15), c(schwab = 0.0428571428571429, 
gs = 0.0714285714285714, pnc = 0.0714285714285714, citi = 0.0857142857142857, 
amex = 0.0857142857142857, spgl = 0.0857142857142857, jpm = 0.1, 
brk = 0.1, ms = 0.114285714285714, wf = 0.114285714285714, bofa = 0.128571428571429
))

table(res <- sapply(degree.l, names), pos = row(res))
```

Also refer to this question for ways to rank it solidly based on the sort I got:

[Frequency of appearance in list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68491907/frequency-of-appearance-in-list-of-lists)

Comment: Can you please update with the expected output so that it becomes more clear

Comment: If it is based on the values, try `table(do.call(rbind, lapply(degree.l, function(x) stack(setNames(dplyr::dense_rank(round(x, 3)), names(x)))))[2:1])`

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is actually what I had in mind. Can you explain how does this function work though? @akrun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We loop over the named `list` ('degree.l'), get the rank on the `round`ed vectors with `dense_rank`, named it with the original vector names, `stack` into a two column data.frame, `rbind` the `list` elements and get the frequency `table`

```
table(do.call(rbind, lapply(degree.l, function(x) 
    stack(setNames(dplyr::dense_rank(round(x, 3)), names(x)))))[2:1])
```

-output

```
       values
ind      1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  schwab 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
  pnc    0 3 0 0 0 0 0
  jpm    0 0 1 1 1 0 0
  amex   0 0 2 0 1 0 0
  gs     0 1 0 1 0 1 0
  ms     0 0 1 1 1 0 0
  bofa   0 0 0 1 1 1 0
  citi   0 0 1 1 0 0 1
  wf     0 0 0 0 3 0 0
  spgl   0 0 1 1 1 0 0
  brk    0 0 0 1 0 2 0
```

Comment: How's this different from before? I want them to be in the same rank if the difference is not significant. Like we would have a level that evaluates if they are different or not. Each time, the rankings might not go up to 11, since some of them might go in the same ranking.

Comment: @statwoman your expected output is not clear.  Can you update your post with expected.

Comment: @statwoman your description is `What I want to look into is how many times a certain element has appeared in a specific position (For instance, "pnc" has appeared in 2nd position twice and in third position once).`  If you want the total, then wrap with `rowSums`

Comment: I edited it, is it better? Sorry, it's just a bit hard to write what I want it to be like.